# Inverse of a matrix with the first standard basis vector as its first column

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an invertible matrix $n$ by $n$ matrix of the shape $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\c&A\end{bmatrix},$$ where $0$ denotes the $n-1$ zero column vector and $A$ is an $n-1$ by $n-1$ matrix.

Is the inverse of this matrix of the same shape? If not, can someone give me a counterexample?

I confirmed this in the case where $n=2$ by explicitly calculating the inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, we can compute the specific inverse in general.  Note that a matrix of that shape will be invertible if and only if $A$ is invertible.  More over, its inverse will be given by
$$
M^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&0\\-A^{-1}c&A^{-1}}
$$
As you can verify by block-matrix multiplication.